# How do i recreate a user domain-joined profile folder on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, user-profile

I just deleted a user profile folder on Windows 2008 server (c:\Users\username) and now everytime i log on as the user windows tells me that it couldn't load the profile and it'll use a temporary folder.

Is there any way to tell Windows 2008 server to recreate the user profile folder?

The server is domain-joined and the user is from the domain.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found it:

1. Right click on computer, and select
   propertie
2. Right click on computer, and select
   properties
3. Click on System Advanced
   Configuration
4. Select Advanced options Tab
5. On user profiles frames click on
   configuration
6. Select the user from the list and
   then delete it
7. Now the profile will be respawned
   the next time the user logs on

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it is not sufficient to delete the profile folder is that there is one registry key below HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList per profile. If that key exists, Windows thinks the profile is still somewhat "alive" and won't create a new one. Instead, you get a temporary profile. This happens since Vista, in XP you could simple remove the profile folder without caring for the ProfileList registry key.

I have explained this in detail in my article [Deleting a Local User Profile – Not as easy as one Might Assume](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2008/10/deleting-a-local-user-profile-not-as-easy-as-one-might-assume/).